# How to check if an Array of strings is sorted in alphabetical order or not using Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin

I am given a list of strings and I need to see if they are in alphabetical order.

I know I need to use a for loop and check the first character of each string but I don't know how to progress from there.

```
for (item in array)
     println(item[0])
```

For example `["adam", "ben", "chloe"]` should return `true`.

And likewise for `["ben", "adam", "chloe"]` should return `false`.

Answer (score 14):

**UPD:** Since Kotlin 1.2 the following is available:

Most efficient variant, creates the smallest amount of intermediate objects:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).asSequence().zipWithNext { a, b -> a <= b }.all { it }
```

Note on efficiency: Creates only two `Sequence` objects and one function object. Uses `Boolean` constants as an intermediate value. The final `all` invocation is inlined as a `while` loop over the sequence.

Slightly less efficient variant:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).asSequence().windowed(2).all { (a, b) -> a <= b }
```

It's slightly less efficient, as it creates creates intermediate `List(a, b)` for every element of the original list.

Both of these variants were listed in the answers below by @Billbucket and @AshishChaudhary.

---

**Old answer, for previous versions of Kotlin:**

Here is a one liner:

```
val a = listOf("a", "b", "c")
a.zip(a.drop(1)).all { (a, b) -> a <= b }
// true
```

Explanation:

`a.zip(a.drop(1))` returns pairs of neighbour elements. If in every pair first element is less or equal to the next, array is in order.

If you want to improve performance, you can wrap your array in lazy sequence first. In this case array won't be copied:

```
a.asSequence().let { it.zip(it.drop(1)).all { (a, b) -> a < b }  }
```

The whole thing is `O(N)` (single pass through array), which is optimal for this task.

Comment: Better to stop when a violation is found. This works better in place of `.all` : `.none { (a, b) -> a > b }`

Comment: @AshishChaudhary it doesn't matter. These functions are symmetrical and both stop when first violation is found.

Comment: Since you are actually aware that your "best" variant creates unnecessary intermediate objects you should be calling it "least inefficient" rather than "most efficient". There are better ways to do that.

Comment: @AlexeyNezhdanov, if you are referring to the intermediate `Boolean` objects, then please note, that autoboxing will reuse `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` constants (already efficient enough), and they will probably be optimized away by JIT.

Comment: @AlexeyNezhdanov, also, if you know a better way, please post it as a separate answer (or give the link to an existing answer).

Comment: @AlexeyNezhdanov I've added a note on efficiency. To reiterate: the top variant creates a constant number of intermediate objects that is independent from the input size.

Comment: @Aivean I thought that it is obvious, but apparently not. The most efficient way is when you don't create a single intermediate object. Kotlin makes this task rather laborious forcing people to write inefficient code and hope that JIT will fix it.

Comment: @AlexeyNezhdanov, gotcha. You're right, of course. I'd also add that there is even more efficient way — not execute any code at all. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

you can use a simple one-liner:

```
array.zipWithNext { s1, s2 -> s1 <= s2 }.all { it }
```

Comment: this makes a.zip(a.drop(1)) even nicer :)

Comment: `array.zipWithNext().all { it.first <= it.second }`

Answer (score 1):

Im sure you could do your desired task completely using a for-loop.

However in Kotlin I personally think it would be more idiomatic to do something like this using [**until**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html):

```
fun isAlphabetical(stringsArray: Array<String>): Boolean {
    if (stringsArray.size < 2) return true
    return (1 until stringsArray.size).none { stringsArray[it] <= stringsArray[it - 1] }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val testCases = arrayOf(arrayOf("adam", "ben", "chloe"), arrayOf("ben", "adam", "chloe"))

    for(testCase : Array<String> in testCases){
        println("The strings are: ${testCase.joinToString()}")
        if (isAlphabetical(testCase)) {
            println("Strings are in alphabetical order.\n")
        } else {
            println("Strings are not in alphabetical order.\n")        
        }
    }    
}
```

**Output:**

```
The strings are: adam, ben, chloe
Strings are in alphabetical order.

The strings are: ben, adam, chloe
Strings are not in alphabetical order.
```

Basically you only compare each element of the array with the previous element (using `<=`) if the length of the array is more than `1`.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and easy way to accomplish it is by sorting and comparing the original list with the sorted one (two lists are equal when they have the exact same elements in the same order). Since you mentioned you are dealing with an array, you first need to convert it to a list. This solution is not the best in terms of performance (it's `O(n log n)` and converts the array twice to a list) but it's very readable:

```
val test = array.asList() == array.asList().sorted()
```

The full code for your question could be:

```
println(if (array.asList() == array.asList().sorted()) "Strings are in alphabetical order." else "Strings are not in alphabetical order.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
val list = listOf("a", "b", "c")
list.windowed(2).none { (a, b) -> a > b }
// true
```

Comment: `windowed` is a good catch. But note, it is available only since Kotlin 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to compare arbitrary `Comparable` list:

```kotlin
fun <T : Comparable<T>> isCollectionSortedAsc(list: Collection<T>): Boolean {
  return list.zipWithNext { a, b -> a.compareTo(b) == -1 }.all { it }
}
```

Based on the accepted answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47296632/4919972

Comment: This answer has worse performance because `asSequence()` is not used so `zipWithNext()` goes through the whole collection and returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution :)

```
data class Result(val isInOrder: Boolean, val lastString: String) {
    val toString = when {
        isInOrder -> "Strings are in alphabetical order."
        else -> "Strings are not in alphabetical order."
    }
}

fun Array<String>.isInAlphabeticalOrder() =
    this.fold(Result(true, ""), { acc, word -> Result(acc.isInOrder && acc.lastString < word, word) })

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val test1 = arrayOf("adam", "ben", "chloe")
    val test2 = arrayOf("ben", "adam", "chloe")
    println(test1.isInAlphabeticalOrder().toString)
    println(test2.isInAlphabeticalOrder().toString)
}
```